# Convert from List<Dictionary<DateTime, Points[]>> to Dictionary<DateTime, Points[]>

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have `List<Dictionary<DateTime, Points[]>> taskResult` generated from tasks

```
var taskResult = tasks.Select(t => t.Result).ToList();
var data = new Dictionary<DateTime, Points[]>();
```

in my function I want to return `Dictionary<DateTime, Points[]> data` but I cant figure out how to do that. I tried using foreach but had no luck

Comment: Your question is effectively "how do I merge multiple dictionaries into one?" How exactly do you want them to be merged? Is it just a case of take all key value pairs from all dictionaries and put them into one? What if there end up being duplicate keys?

Comment: You have a List of Dictionary, and you plan to return a Single Dictionary? Do you want `taskResult.FirstOrDefault()`?

Comment: what is the type returned by the tasks (t.Result) ?

Comment: What happens if the dictionaries contain duplicate keys? Do you want to merge the points by key?

Comment: What is the difference between Point[] and Points[]? Are all DateTime values unique between dictionaries?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Enumerable.SelectMany` extension method is right tool for the job, which combines many collections into one.  Dictionary is a collection of key-value pairs.

```
var combined = dictionaries
    .SelectMany(dictionary => dictionary.Select(pair => pair))
    .GroupBy(pair => pair.Key)
    .ToDictionary(
        group => group.Key, 
        group => group.SelectMany(pair => pair.Value).ToArray());
```

Approach above will merge points of same date if original dictionaries contain duplicated dates

Because `Dictionary` implements `IEnumerable` you can remove `.Select` in first call of `SelectMany`.
Alternative for `.GroupBy` is `.ToLookup` method, which can have multiple values per one key.

```
var combined = dictionaries
    .SelectMany(dictionary => dictionary)
    .ToLookup(pair => pair.Key, pair.Value)
    .ToDictionary(
        lookup => lookup.Key, 
        lookup => lookup.SelectMany(points => points).ToArray());
```